# Does Selenium 2.5 work with Firefox 28?

Tags: firefox, selenium

I have found so many versions of Firefox and Selenium but not the Firefox version and Selenium version which I am using. I am using Firefox 28 and Selenium 2.5 but the error is occurring as unable to connect to host.

So I'd like to know does this combination of Firefox and Selenium work?

Comment: Are you talking about Selenium **IDE** 2.5.0 released this year? Or Selenium WebDriver 2.5.0 which was released in 2011?

Answer (score 0):

No. Selenium v2.41, released very recently, is the only one to have native events support for Firefox.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG

**At the time of writing Selenium supports:**

```
v2.41.0
=======
   17 (immediately previous ESR release)
   24 (current ESR release)
   27 (immediately previous release
   28 (current release)
```

So your solution is to either upgrade Selenium or downgrade Firefox.